# Finding all function calls through a Webpack plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm writing a Webpack plugin that will find all references to i18n/translation functions with the aim of finding all texts that need translations and then uploading them to a translation service.

Any pointers on how to get started? Which hooks should I be using?

Comment: You are writing something but you have no idea how to do it?

Comment: Yes, is that an uncommon scenario in your world? Do you always know the exact way you're going to code something before you do it? I have somewhat of an idea - I know that I'm going to do this through a Webpack plugin using its hooks, but beyond that I'm not sure yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up using `compiler.hooks.compilation` to get the compilation object, then the following to hook into when Webpack parses source code:

```js
        normalModuleFactory.hooks.parser
          .for('javascript/auto')
          .tap(pluginName, parserHandler);
        normalModuleFactory.hooks.parser
          .for('javascript/dynamic')
          .tap(pluginName, parserHandler);
        normalModuleFactory.hooks.parser
          .for('javascript/esm')
          .tap(pluginName, parserHandler);
```

And parserHandler uses `parser.hooks.evaluate` hooks to find function and method calls. This part is a bit tricky, because Webpack needs to be fooled into thinking CallExpression callee's are identifiers, otherwise Webpack won't call hooks on method/function calls you're interested in.

Something like this:

```js
           // Handler for tricking Webpack into running hooks on expressions we're interested in,
          // because it doesn't do it otherwise
          const evaluateHandler = (expr: Identifier | MemberExpression) => {
            const funcName = isMemberExpression(expr)
              ? expr.property.name
              : expr.name;
            if (isCorrectFunction(funcName)) {
              return new BasicEvaluatedExpression()
                .setRange(expr.range)
                .setExpression(expr)
                .setIdentifier(SPECIAL_IDENTIFIER);
            }
          };

          // Find all relevant function calls and mark them as identifiers to trick Webpack
          // Into invoking the `call` hooks for these CallExpressions
          parser.hooks.evaluate
            .for('MemberExpression')
            .tap(pluginName, evaluateHandler);

          // Do the same for when functions are destructured out of the parent object
          // These are actually Identifiers, but the Parser implementation doesn't mark them so for some reason
          parser.hooks.evaluate
            .for('Identifier')
            .tap(pluginName, evaluateHandler);

          // Get all relevant function call CallExpressions
          parser.hooks.call
            .for(SPECIAL_IDENTIFIER)
            .tap(
              pluginName,
              (expr: CallExpression<MemberExpression | Identifier>) => {
                // FUNCTION CALL FOUND HERE
              }
            );
```