# Updating chunks with extra code after initial chunks have been generated with a Webpack plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm writing a webpack plugin that is supposed to do the following: When webpack has created chunks, this plugin will look for references of specific functions in those chunks and then add extra code in those chunks depending on the found function calls.

This is supposed to be a mechanism for pulling translation texts from an API and then loading only those that are needed in each chunk. And for figuring out which translations are needed, I'm trying to track all calls to translation functions in each chunk.

If I just needed to find all translation calls, it'd be relatively easy, something like what I described here: [Finding all function calls through a Webpack plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784230/finding-all-function-calls-through-a-webpack-plugin)

The issue in this case is that I need to find these calls per chunk and then afterwards update those chunks with extra code (actual translations pulled from server).

At the very least I'd like to update the translation .json once all translations are found. This .json is imported somewhere in the application.